# Android - widget with onTouchListener

Tags: android, widget

I'm a begginer as far as widgets go. I have started by designing a simple one to understand the mechanics. The end goal is to have a widget with an ImageView that can accept touch events (multitouch to be exact). Is this possible or am I trying in vein ? If it is possible can someone direct me as to how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

In Android the a GUI element is called a `View` and yes, you can make your own views (including multitouch). Unfortunately this topic is too broad to give a full answer but check the developer page at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html.

Edit:
Overriding `onTouchEvent` of [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) will give you access to touches.

Comment: you're right..i should say more about it. The entire widget is a simple ImageView on which I can handle multitouch events. nothing more.